# Finding random teams with PHP script

Tags: php, arrays

I have a problem which I thought I could solve with a PHP script - but apparently, it is much more complicated than I thought.

**Task**: We have 70 people and want to divide them in 17 Teams. Every person should appear once or twice, but obviously, not twice in the same team.

**Thoughts**: Define an array with the persons, and then randomly sort them into the teams.

`$persons = array("name1","name2","name3", "... until name70"};`

**My first idea:** I thought it would be easy, but it is not. I think, what I need is to assign a new value to each of the persons, so that it looks like this:

`$persons = array("name1" => "team1", "name2" => "team 14", "name3" => "team 10", ".....");`

Then `print` this, and then do this again. But: The second round would have to compare the new array to the first one, because no pair of values should appear twice. So, if "name2" is paired with "team14" in the first round, the pair has to be different the second round. I didn't find a solution to achieve this.

**A second idea:** I thought I could do this by using a `while` loop to do the same thing 17 times. The `while` loop should modify the original `$persons` array to contain only 5 names and delete the rest of the values. But I would have to compare the new array to the existing ones in order to not use the same names more than twice. This leaves me with the problem that I will have too less people for the last teams.

As I am at the beginning of this, and my original idea just led to more problems, I am glad for every hint you have, also for functions I could check out. I know some PHP, but really not that much, so there is a great chance I haven't notices the solution is rather easy...

Comment: what is the criteria on appearing twice on the team? and can they all be on different teams of more or less same sizes? what are the default team sizes?

Comment: This seems a funny task, but stackoverflow is not a site for this questions. You should ask this at codegolf: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ that's another stack exchange community that allows experiments and code writting.

Comment: something like `shuffle($persons); $teams = array_chunk($persons, 17);` done.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Thanks for pointing that out. I will do next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teams and people become simple numeric index array, then an associative array teammembers where the index is the team and the values are the member names.  Loop through the people, put them on a team.  Increment the team counter.  When you reach the last team, reset the team counter, for giggles shuffle the order of the teams (to avoid team1,team2,team3,team1,team2,team3 pattern).

```
<?php

// define our people and teams as simple arrays
for($i=1;$i<71;$i++){
    $people[]="person".$i;
}

for($i=1;$i<18;$i++){
    $teams[]="team".$i;
}

// what team are we adding to?
$teamidx=0;

// loop through people, add them to a team
// when you run out of teams, shuffle the team
// order for giggles and start back at the first
// team
for($i=0;$i<count($people);$i++){
    $teammembers[$teams[$teamidx]][]=$people[$i];
    $teamidx++;
    if($teamidx==count($teams)){
        $teamidx=0;
        shuffle($teams);
    }
}

print_r($teammembers);

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply - that did the trick, and man, did I learn a lot! One question: Would it be possible to modify this script, so that everybody appears twice? By duplicating it, I manage to double the team size, but in that case, persons may appear twice on the same team.

Comment: Sure, just need to add a check with a if-then to see if the person is already on that team before you add them to it...