# PHP randomly assign people to a team

Tags: php, random, shuffle

I'm currently building up a little game, where users need to be randomly assigned to teams.

What I got is a table in the database, where the logged in users are listed. Also, each user has a column for the team.

Now in PHP, I got all users stored in a variable, like the following (output of `var_export`)

```
array ( 0 => array ( 'ID' => '3', 'name' => 'olaf', 'team' => NULL, ), 1 => array ( 'ID' => '4', 'name' => 'Peter', 'team' => NULL, ), 2 => array ( 'ID' => '5', 'name' => 'chris', 'team' => NULL, ), 3 => array ( 'ID' => '6', 'name' => 'günther', 'team' => NULL, ), )
```

Now I got two teams, Team Red and Team Blue. My goal is, that every person has randomly been assigned to one of the two teams, however, both teams should have a similar amount of team members (or if an odd number of users is logged in, one team can have one more player).

When assigned, I would then write the information to the database. However, I'd like to always be able to shuffle the teams and then have new teams.

The number of logged in users can vary between 2 and 50 persons.

So far, I thought about multiple ways of doing it, like randomly picking a number between 1 and sizeof(array of users) and then assigning him a team, however, I couldn't get it to work...

Also I [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40789143/finding-random-teams-with-php-script) Stackoverflow post, however, using this code, my team Red always had player 1 and 3 or 1 and 4 and my team Blue always had player 2 and 3 or 2 and 4. It never happened, that player 1 was in team red. However, as mentioned, the mix should be completely random.

Can anybody help me out with this or has an idea, how I could manage to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be an example:

```
<?php

// just preparing the set of players for the demonstration
$numberOfPLayers = 6;
$players = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $numberOfPLayers; $i++) {
    $players[] = [
        'id' => $i,
        'name' => sprintf("Player %d", $i + 1),
        'team' => null 
    ];
}

// here starts the actual assignment
shuffle($players);

array_walk($players, function(&$player, $index) {
    $player['team'] = $index % 2 ? "Red" : "Blue";
});

usort($players, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['id'] <=> $b['id'];
});

// just a test output of the set of players
print_r($players);
```

The code snippet creates a list of players, you can play around with the number of players. It first shuffles the players, then assigns teams alternatingly, so evenly and finally again sorts the set of players.

One possible output is (depends on the randomizing shuffle of course):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0
            [name] => Player 1
            [team] => Blue
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Player 2
            [team] => Red
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Player 3
            [team] => Red
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Player 4
            [team] => Blue
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => Player 5
            [team] => Red
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [name] => Player 6
            [team] => Blue
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to solve your problem. You can now easily reset the teams by calling `createTeams($playerArray);`. The function first checks if there's an even amount of players. If that is the case then every team gets half of total players. Otherwise, a team randomly gets 1 more or less player by rounding the `$playersPerTeam` up or down. Next it shuffles the player array 4 times to create a random player list.

After that you have two options of return values. The first one picks the asigned number of players from the `$players` array. Then it returns an array with the teams.

The other, last, way involves the same method as the first but now it sets the `[team]` variable of the player object as well. Then it returns the `$players` array but with the assigned team name.

```php
function createTeams($players) {
  $totalPlayers = count($players);

  if($totalPlayers % 2 == 0) { //even amount of players
    $playersRed = $playersBlue = $totalPlayers / 2;
  } else { //odd amount of players
    $randInt = rand(1,100);
    $playersPerTeam = $totalPlayers / 2;
    if($randInt <= 50) { //team red has an advantage of 1 extra player
      $playersRed = round($playersPerTeam, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
      $playersBlue = round($playersPerTeam, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
    } else { //team blue has an advantage of 1 extra player
      $playersRed = round($playersPerTeam, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
      $playersBlue = round($playersPerTeam, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
    }
  }

  //This should be random enough for this purpose
  for ($i=0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    shuffle($players);
  }


  //One way to return the teams.
  // $teamRed  = array_slice($players, 0, $playersRed);
  // $teamBlue = array_slice($players, $playersRed, $playersBlue);
  // return array('red' => $teamRed , 'blue' => $teamBlue);

  //Other way to return the createTeams
  for ($i=0; $i < $totalPlayers; $i++) {
    if ($i < $playersRed) { //player is gonna be in team red
      $players[$i]['team'] = 'red';
    } else { //player is gonna be in team blue
      $players[$i]['team'] = 'blue';
    }
  }
  return $players;
}
```

Testing it with this player array:

```php
$players = array ( 0 => array ( 'ID' => '3', 'name' => 'olaf', 'team' => NULL), 1 => array ( 'ID' => '4', 'name' => 'Peter', 'team' => NULL), 2 => array ( 'ID' => '5', 'name' => 'chris', 'team' => NULL), 3 => array ( 'ID' => '6', 'name' => 'günther', 'team' => NULL), 4 => array ( 'ID' => '7', 'name' => 'Max', 'team' => NULL));

for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) {
  print_r(createTeams($players));
  echo "<br><br>";
}
```

Gives the following output:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 4 [name] => Peter [team] => red ) [1] => Array ( [ID] => 6 [name] => günther [team] => red ) [2] => Array ( [ID] => 5 [name] => chris [team] => blue ) [3] => Array ( [ID] => 7 [name] => Max [team] => blue ) [4] => Array ( [ID] => 3 [name] => olaf [team] => blue ) )
>
> Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 3 [name] => olaf [team] => red ) [1] => Array ( [ID] => 5 [name] => chris [team] => red ) [2] => Array ( [ID] => 6 [name] => günther [team] => red ) [3] => Array ( [ID] => 4 [name] => Peter [team] => blue ) [4] => Array ( [ID] => 7 [name] => Max [team] => blue ) )
>
> Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 3 [name] => olaf [team] => red ) [1] => Array ( [ID] => 6 [name] => günther [team] => red ) [2] => Array ( [ID] => 5 [name] => chris [team] => blue ) [3] => Array ( [ID] => 4 [name] => Peter [team] => blue ) [4] => Array ( [ID] => 7 [name] => Max [team] => blue ) )
>
> Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 6 [name] => günther [team] => red ) [1] => Array ( [ID] => 7 [name] => Max [team] => red ) [2] => Array ( [ID] => 3 [name] => olaf [team] => blue ) [3] => Array ( [ID] => 5 [name] => chris [team] => blue ) [4] => Array ( [ID] => 4 [name] => Peter [team] => blue ) )
>
> Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 5 [name] => chris [team] => red ) [1] => Array ( [ID] => 6 [name] => günther [team] => red ) [2] => Array ( [ID] => 3 [name] => olaf [team] => red ) [3] => Array ( [ID] => 4 [name] => Peter [team] => blue ) [4] => Array ( [ID] => 7 [name] => Max [team] => blue ) )

Hope this helps! If not, please comment.

Answer (score 1):

I see there is an accepted answer, but I figured I would post my answer as well as I started to work on this last night and figured it out this morning...

***Check it out on the online parser*** **3v4l**: https://3v4l.org/O8hOh

***Use colors to style the table:*** https://3v4l.org/ZUl5p

Takes array and iterates through using `foreach()` then uses `rand()` to create a new array `$checks` and then checks if value `!in_array() && !array_key_exists()` is present in that new array, if it is not, then we iterate the counter and push the new value and the gamers name into the new array. We wrap this all in while loop that checks if counter is equal to `count($arr)` --> number of gamers, dynamically pulled from arrays `count()`.

We use a second conditional to make sure the new array `count($check) === count($arr)`, both are the same number, move forward with pushing the team into the original array where  `key=NULL` or `team=NULL`. `foreach()` loop to construct `$gamers` array. Push original values back into new array, then conditional to check if divisible by two as the `$checks` array will always randomly assign the number of players a new number each time invoked, `if($check[$value['name']] % 2 == 0)` assign team 2 -->   `$gamers[$key]['team'] = 2;`.
or `$gamers[$key]['team'] = 'blue';`, `else{ $gamers[$key]['team'] = 1 }` or `else{ $gamers[$key]['team'] = 'Red' };`

The old array that originally held the players that had `NULL` values for the key `team` now holds the newly assigned team/s.

**Basic code with explanations in code comments:**

```php
$arr = array ( 0 => array ( 'ID' => '3', 'name' => 'olaf', 'team' => NULL, ), 1 => array ( 'ID' => '4', 'name' => 'Peter', 'team' => NULL, ), 2 => array ( 'ID' => '5', 'name' => 'chris', 'team' => NULL, ), 3 => array ( 'ID' => '6', 'name' => 'günther', 'team' => NULL, ), );
// count the number of player in the array and assign to variable
$numOfPlayers = count($arr);

// initiate an empty array to hold the values of the players random unique numbers
$check = array();

  $i = 0; // use a counter to evaluate whether number of players set in array is met
  while($i < count($arr)){ // iterate through foreach loop until we have met the number of players using while loop
    // iterate through each time the while loop fires to get the $value 
    foreach($arr as $key => $value){
      // create a random number between 0 and the number of players present in array 
      // to check and pass into new array if is not set yet
      $random = rand(1,$numOfPlayers);
      // conditional that check if the random number is in the new array, if not we push that as a value into the new array
      // we also check if the persons name is set as a key, if not, we push that as a key into the new aray
      if(!in_array($random, $check) && !array_key_exists($value['name'], $check)){
        // set the new key/value pairs and iterate the counter for the while loop
        $check[$value['name']] = $random;
        $i++;
      }
    }
  }
  // Now see if the two arrays $check and $arr are equal in count
  if(count($check) === count($arr)){
    // now assign teams using modulus
    foreach($arr as $key => $value){ 
      // construct the old array with original values
      $gamers[$key] = $value; 
      // if value is divisible by 2, assign to specific team change operator here 
      // if you want to swap what team get the odd numbered players   
      if($check[$value['name']] % 2 == 0){       
        $gamers[$key]['team'] = 2;
      // else if not divisible by two assign to other team     
      }else{
        $gamers[$key]['team'] = 1;
      }
    }     
  }
```

**As a function:**

```php
function constTeams($arr){
  $numOfPlayers = count($arr);

  $check = array();

  $i = 0;
  while($i < count($arr)){
    foreach($arr as $key => $value){
      $random = rand(1,$numOfPlayers); 
      if(!in_array($random, $check) && !array_key_exists($value['name'], $check)){
        $check[$value['name']] = $random;
        $i++;
      }
    }
  }
  if(count($check) === count($arr)){
    foreach($arr as $key => $value){ 
      $gamers[$key] = $value;     
      if($check[$value['name']] % 2 == 0){        
        $gamers[$key]['team'] = 'Blue';
      }else{
        $gamers[$key]['team'] = 'Red';
      }
    }     
  }
  return $gamers;
}
```

**An output of `var_dump(constTeams($arr));` using the function above which will change each time invoked:**

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["ID"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "olaf"
    ["team"]=>
    string(3) "Red"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["ID"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Peter"
    ["team"]=>
    string(4) "Blue"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["ID"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "chris"
    ["team"]=>
    string(4) "Blue"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["ID"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "günther"
    ["team"]=>
    string(3) "Red"
  }
}
```

**Use with array of odd numbered players:**

```php
$players = array ( 
  0 => array ( 'ID' => '3', 'name' => 'olaf', 'team' => NULL, ), 
  1 => array ( 'ID' => '4', 'name' => 'Peter', 'team' => NULL, ), 
  2 => array ( 'ID' => '5', 'name' => 'chris', 'team' => NULL, ), 
  3 => array ( 'ID' => '6', 'name' => 'günther', 'team' => NULL, ), 
  4 => array ( 'ID' => '7', 'name' => 'John', 'team' => NULL, ), 
  5 => array ( 'ID' => '8', 'name' => 'Jack', 'team' => NULL, ), 
  6 => array ( 'ID' => '9', 'name' => 'Bob', 'team' => NULL, ), 
  7 => array ( 'ID' => '10', 'name' => 'Jake', 'team' => NULL, ), 
  8 => array ( 'ID' => '11', 'name' => 'Bill', 'team' => NULL, ) 
) ;

$output = '
  <table>
    ';
  foreach(constTeams($players) as $key => $value){
      $output .= '
      <tr border="1">
        <td>'.$value['name'].'</td>
        <td>Team: '.$value['team'].'</td>
      </tr>';    
  }
  $output .= '
  </table>';
```

**OUTPUT: Randomly changes each time function is invoked.** 
NOTE: odd numbered players will be determined by the operator in the modulus equation conditional, change that to change which team gets the overpowered number of players. `==` or `!=` --> here: `if($check[$value['name']] % 2 == 0)`

[image]